# Redux Reducer Mystery On full State upload

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

Why can't update the entire state at once on Redux?

Look this typical Slice working Perfect as usually:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    userName: "pepe",
    userLevel: 0,
    actualStage: 1
}

export const gameSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'game',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setName: (state, action) => {
            state.userName = action.payload
        },
        incrementLevel: (state) => {
            state.userLevel += 1
        },
        setStage: (state, action) => {
            state.actualStage = action.payload
        },
        setVariasCosas: (state, action) => {
            state.userName = action.payload.name
            state.userLevel = action.payload.newLevel
            state.actualStage = action.payload.newStage              
        }    
    },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { setName, incrementLevel, setStage, setVariasCosas } = gameSlice.actions

export default gameSlice.reducer
```

When i call it as expected from anywhere:

```
dispatch(setVariasCosas({
      userName : "paco",
      userLevel : 99,
      actualStage : 7
    }))
```

It Works Good like this:

```
setVariasCosas: (state, action) => {
    state.userName = action.payload.name
    state.userLevel = action.payload.newLevel
    state.actualStage = action.payload.newStage
}
```

And also like this:

```
setVariasCosas: (state, action) => {                        
        return {
            userName: action.payload.userName,
            userLevel: action.payload.userLevel,
            actualStage: action.payload.actualStage 
        }            
    }
```

But no works like this:

```
 setVariasCosas: (state, action) => {
        state = action.payload
    }
```

And only like this:

```
 setVariasCosas: (state, action) => {
       return action.payload
    }
```

There's any way to do this with a

```
setVariasCosas: (state, action) => {
        state = // someting here?
    }
```

What about that? And why not working state = ? Since u can state.name = "pepe" working good? It doesn't make sense to me and I need to understand it xD

I would love to put state = because its easy readable for everybody.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Writing Reducers with Immer - Resetting and Replacing State](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state).

You can either modify *the object in the variable `state`*, or return a new state.

But what you do is *reassign the variable state*. That means the original object is thrown away, and the variable has a new value now - but from the outside of that function, that is not visible.

So instead of

```js
setVariasCosas: (state, action) => {
  // bad: don't reassign `state`
  state = action.payload;
};
```

do this instead:

```js
setVariasCosas: (state, action) => {
  return action.payload;
};
```

Comment: thanks for the link! I really needed to see that from the ofical doc! thanks!